# Implementation of vanishing point algorithm using opencv

Tags: opencv, vanishing-point

I am trying to make an ARDRONE(a quadrotor) to navigate trhough a maze.

I am using ROS-ELECTRIC and OPENCV. I have implemented hough line transfrom. I need to implement the vanishing point algortihm to make the robot navigate autonomously. I am new to opencv . Could you guys please suggest the approach to attain the vanishing point? and also will it serve the purpose of navigating the robot through a maze and find the target?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can check this http://marcosnieto.net/#PhD in the code.

OpenCV implementation based on the author's PhD thesis.

It works for me, but up to 2 vanishing point in my test.

Comment: This is the correct link: https://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/lane-markings-detection-and-vanishing-point-detection-with-opencv/